# Is it possible to compile XNA game assets in the content folder into a DLL?

Tags: dll, xna

When a XNA project is compiled/built, the Content project that comes with the template builds all the assets into xnb files, then dumps them into a Content directory.

Is it somehow possible that I could have the game assets compiled into a .dll file instead of the Content folder?

Followup question: Is it possible for the assets to reside in the game project itself instead of having a content project? How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following article.  It will explain to you how to store your XNB files in a DLL binary.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604975.aspx#ID4E5D

For your second question, no it is not possible.  The reason you need to store your assets in the Content project, is because XNA utilizes a "[Content Pipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447745.aspx)", which essentially converts various media into an XNA accessible form.

Comment: I've seen that page and it didn't work for me, but I'll try it again. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You would only do this before you release, as you need to package the XNB files into a DLL.  So just keep in mind to only do this once you have your final product.